# how to save meta box value?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I've created a meta box. The code is:

```
// Create your custom meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'hotel_amenities' );
   // Add a custom meta box to a post
    function hotel_amenities( $post ) { 
        add_meta_box(
                'Meta Box Amenities', // ID, should be a string
                'Amenities', // Meta Box Title
                'amenities_content', // Your call back function, this is where your form field will go
                'post', // The post type you want this to show up on, can be post, page, or custom post type
                'normal', // The placement of your meta box, can be normal or side
                'high' // The priority in which this will be displayed
            ); 
    }

    // Content for the custom meta box
    function amenities_content( $post ) { 
        echo '<label>Bed room</label>'; 
        echo '<input type="text" name="amenity_bed_room" value="" />'; 
    }

    // Save your meta box content
    add_action( 'save_post', 'save_amenities' );
    // save newsletter content
    function save_amenities(){ 
        global $post; 
        // Get our form field
        if( $_POST ) : 
             $amenities_meta = esc_attr( $_POST['amenity_bed_room'] ); 
             // Update post meta
             update_post_meta($post->ID, '_amenities_custom_meta', $amenities_meta); 
        endif; 
    }
```

It shows a meta box on admin post page with a text field. but it gets blank if I save or update the post after I put some thing on the text field.

[image: screen shot]

Seems `function save_amenities()` is not working. What I am doing wrong in this code?

Also for getting that value I use the function below. Is that correct?

```
//get amenities meta box values
function get_amenities_meta_box() {
    global $post;
    $meta_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_amenities_custom_meta', true); 
}
```

Comment: [examples](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&pagesize=50&q=%2bsave_post%20%2badd_meta_boxes%20is%3aanswer)

Comment: You're missing `if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {return;}`, there is an example here as well: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: Hah. Word to the "meat box".

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things going wrong there. The final value that you want to see will be displayed by the value attribute in the `amenities_content` function. Right now it is just displaying an empty string (""). Try putting any value in that attribute and you should see it show up in the meta box (`value="this is a test"`).

The `save_amenities` function should take `$post_id` as a parameter. You'll need that to update the post meta-data and give a real value for the `amenities_content` function to echo back to the admin screen.

The `amenities_content` function should really have a nonce field that should then be verified by the `save_amenities` function. And user input should be sanitized before it is saved (I'm doing it both when I save it and when I display it. I'm not sure if that's necessary.)

try this out for the `amenities_content` function:

```
function amenities_content( $post ) {
    // This is the value that was saved in the save_amenities function
    $bed_room = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_amenity_bed_room', true );

    wp_nonce_field( 'save_amenity', 'amenity_nonce' );

    echo '<label>Bed room</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="amenity_bed_room"
        value="' . sanitize_text_field( $bed_room ) . '" />';
}
```

and this for the `save_amenities` function:

```
function save_amenities( $post_id ) {

    // Check if nonce is set
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['amenity_nonce'] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['amenity_nonce'], 'save_amenity' ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // Check that the logged in user has permission to edit this post
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    $bed_room = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['amenity_bed_room'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_amenity_bed_room', $bed_room );
}
```